# Remove underline on Spinner Drop down and Change the color of the triangle

Tags: android, drop-down-menu, android-spinner

I am trying to add spinner to my action bar. I am using the cusome spinner. Here is the code.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    style="@style/block" >

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/action_bar_spinner"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:gravity="center" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

And here is the code that I am inflating in the getView method of the SpinnerAdapter to get the custom title of the spinner. Its a Text view.

```
android:id="@+id/spinner_title"
        style="@style/text_title"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:gravity="right"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:text="@string/list_header"
        android:enabled="false"
```

Everything is working fine. But I am getting an underline below the title of the spinner and I want to change the default grey color of the triangle on the right side of the spinner title.

Please advise.

Comment: Can you post screenshot?

Comment: Hi Nikola. thanks for reply. I tried to post screenshot. But could not do so as I need `10 reputations to upload an image. Its a simple spinner with Text in the middle of the action bar like

                            Sample

the problem is its underlined and the triangle color on the right of it is default grey. I need to change it.

Comment: [Full explanation of Garegin's answer here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25911612/383414), including link to website for generating the images.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The underline together with the triangle is a nine-patch resource which is the default background of the `Spinner`. You cannot change the color of the triangle through xml or through code. You'll have to change the entire background.

Comment: Thanks for replying. Can you post some code on how to do it. I tried it but could not implement properly. Appreciate your help.