# Is there any easy way to change Spinner dropdown color in Android?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-spinner, android-theme

[image]

I create my theme to use with the app and the parent of the theme is `Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar`

by the way, I want white background and black text.

**And this is adapter code**

```
     val adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(activity,
                R.array.email_type_array, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item)

     adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item)
     child.spinner.adapter = adapter
```

Is there any easy way to change Spinner dropdown color in Android?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

yes. You can use following attribute fro spinner inside your xml

```
android:popupBackground="YOUR_HEX_COLOR_CODE"
```

to change textcolor etc Make a custom XML file for your spinner item.

**spin_item.xml:**

Then provide it your desired color and sizes :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<TextView  
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textSize="24sp"
    android:textColor="#000000"         
    android:padding="4dp"
    />
```

And then use it like this:

```
val adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(activity,
                R.array.email_type_array, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item)
adapter.setDropDownViewResource(R.layout.spin_item)
```

Comment: Yeah, but the text still white

Comment: Updated the answer. Please check.

Comment: Thank, Actually I've found another way, like this
`android:popupBackground="YOUR_HEX_COLOR_CODE" <--- to set background
android:popupTheme="@android:style/ThemeOverlay.Material.Dark" <--- to set text color`

But I prefer to use your solution because of flexibility. I can set the style of text up to me, not have to follow Material theme

Answer (score 3):

To change the **dropdown background color** use `android:popupBackground="@color/aColor"` on the xml file for your `Spinner` widget:

```
<Spinner
    android:id="@+id/my_spinner"
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:popupBackground="@color/aColor" />
```

When playing with a light theme on your `styles.xml`file the **spinner dropdown icon color** will be black, but pay attention that if you are using `<item name="android:textColorSecondary">@color/aColor</item>` the dropdown icon will pick that color:

```
<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    <item name="android:textColorSecondary">@color/aColor</item>
```

Even your question is about to change the **dropdown background color**  I came here because I was trying to understand why my **spinner dropdown icon color** was with a different color until I discover that (`android:textColorSecondary`) - So hope that helps someone else too.

Answer (score 2):

Through code

```
Spinner spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner);
spinner.getBackground().setColorFilter(getResources().getColor(R.color.red), PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_ATOP);
```

or Through XML

For API 21+:

```
<Spinner
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:backgroundTint="@color/red" />
```

or if you use the support library, you can use:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatSpinner
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:backgroundTint="@color/red" />
```

[Please check the answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32166347/change-color-of-the-drop-down-arrow-of-spinner-in-xml)

Comment: Nope, it changes the background of spinner itself, not the drop-down background color.

Answer (score 1):

In your code, add the following in your onCreate():

```
 Spinner spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner);
 spinner.getBackground().setColorFilter(getResources().getColor(R.color.red), 
 PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_ATOP);
```

Comment: Nope, it changes the background of spinner itself, not the drop-down background color.

Answer (score 1):

Create a new layout file which looks like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<CheckedTextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@android:id/text1"
    style="?android:attr/spinnerDropDownItemStyle"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?android:attr/dropdownListPreferredItemHeight"
    android:ellipsize="marquee"
    android:background="MY REQUIRED COLOR"/>
```

at place where i say `MY REQUIRED COLOR` please set it to the color you want.

Also make sure that you dont change the `android:id` attribute, because the arrayadapter is going to use this to set the text to the textview

Then set it to your arrayadapter during creation like so

```
val adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(activity,
                R.array.email_type_array, .R.layout.custom_ simple_spinner_item)
```

Answer (score 0):

location_Survey_Spin = findViewById(R.id.location_Survey_Spinner);
        location_Survey_Spin.getBackground().setColorFilter(getResources().getColor(R.color.black), PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_ATOP); //it will change spinner dropdown color