# android spinner return background to default

Tags: android, kotlin, android-spinner

My spinner has a background:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatSpinner
            android:id="@+id/jobTypeSpinner"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/ic_spinner_dropdown_line" />
```

In API level 19, it has a very bad appearance,
But if I don't set any background in XML its appearance will be good in API level 19
I want to remove the background programmatically but when I set the following code

```
 jobTypeSpinner.setBackgroundDrawable(null)
or
 jobTypeSpinner.setBackgroundColor(0)
or
 jobTypeSpinner.setBackgroundResource(0)
```

The dropdown icon will gone.
please help me to set default backgrand that has dropdown icon.

Comment: check this link: https://stackoverflow.com/a/32167738/10619147

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is my solution:

Remove `android:background="@drawable/ic_spinner_dropdown_line"` from spinner.

```
<android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatSpinner
    android:id="@+id/jobTypeSpinner"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

In activity/fragment that use the spinner, I assume it's MainActivity.

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private lateinit var defaultSpinnerBackground: Drawable

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        // Save the default spinner background
        defaultSpinnerBackground = jobTypeSpinner.background

        // Set your custom background
        jobTypeSpinner.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.ic_spinner_dropdown_line)
    }
}
```

Whenever you want to reset to default spinner background.

```
jobTypeSpinner.background = defaultSpinnerBackground
```