# How to merge an edittext with spinner in Android?

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-spinner, android-xml

[image: EditText with Spinner/DropDown]

How can I make an EditText with a drop-down in Android?
For reference i have added an image. I am trying to combine an edittext with spinner but I am not able to achieve the same.

Can anyone add suggestion or xml mockup?

Comment: add your xml file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, You can use a `LinearLayout` with a horizontal orientation and create a custom drawable for the rounded border.

## Implementation

First, you need to draw the rounded border by creating a new `Drawable resource` file.

In your `res/drawables` folder create `rounded_border.xml`

#### rounded_border.xml

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <corners android:radius="4dp" />
            <stroke android:width="2dp" android:color="#2E2E2E" />
        </shape>
    </item>
</selector>
```

Then, you can add the `LinearLayout` to your layout as follows.

#### your_layout.xml

```xml
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="56dp"
    android:background="@drawable/rounded_border"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@null"
        android:paddingHorizontal="16dp"
        android:text="(504) 596-3245"
        android:layout_weight="2"/>

    <View
        android:layout_width="2dp"
        android:background="#2E2E2E"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

    <Spinner
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:listitem="@layout/spinner_item_text"
        android:layout_weight="1"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

## Remarks

- You can Customize the border width, color, and radius from the `rounded_border.xml`.

## Final Results

[image: Phone Layout]

Comment: Hey! Thank you. I wasn't able to have the spinner align next to the edit textview. Perhaps where u used layout_weight = "1" did the job!

Comment: How to set the icon on spinner to a different drawable?

Comment: For that you can follow this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/32167738/11784905

Answer (score 0):

could refer this lib demo : https://github.com/z2wenfa/SpinnerEditText

could use the lib directly

```
dependencies {
        compile 'com.github.z2wenfa:SpinnerEditText:1.0.1'
}
```

or could refer: https://github.com/z2wenfa/SpinnerEditText/blob/master/spinneredittext-lib/src/main/java/com/z2wenfa/spinneredittext/SpinnerEditText.java